# Can I display a Google Docs Video in a webapp?

Tags: google-apps-script

I know how to embed a Google Docs Video in my Google site but what I'd really like to do is display some video tutorials via a GAS deployed as a web app - preferably in one tab of a TabPanel but I'm open to suggestions regarding other panel types. Is that supported?

I thought using Class Image might work but I haven't been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot yet embed flash video in HtmlService, although such support is planned

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing a UI app, you might want to consider using HtmlService where you can embed Javascript subject to certain restriction and therefore will be able to embed a video as well

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_html

Comment: Thanks for responding Srik. I'm a total amateur and I haven't yet dabbled with Html at all so I have to admit that I don't know what HtmlService does. But thanks for the tip, I will investigate the possibilities. My UI app is already written - so I was just wondering if I could add another tab and insert my tutorials whilst keeping the whole thing looking tidy.